# How to disable obstacle avoidance on DWA Planner?

Tags: navigation, ros-noetic, dwa-local-planner, obstacle-avoidance

I am using [DWA Planner](https://wiki.ros.org/dwa_local_planner) on ROS Noetic for my navigation. It works perfectly. However, I want to change it's behavior. Instead of avoiding an obstacle, I want my robot to wait until the obstacle gets out of the path. How could I do that?

I tried things like disabling the `VoxelLayer` on `global_costmap`, setting only `staticlayer` on it, and messing around the `distance_bias` parameters on DWA. I tried putting `path_distance` on 100, 0, and it worked the same way. Setting the `goal_distance` to 0 only makes my robot rotate in place. Furthermore, I updated following parameters but no success:

1. path: 100, goal: 20
2. path: 100, goal: 0
3. path: 100, goal: 100
4. path: 0, goal: 100
5. path: 0, goal: 0
6. path: 0, goal: 20
7. path: 32, goal: 100

Answer (score 0):

If you have an active local planner, it will always avoid the object as long as it's in the local costmap. One hack could be to change your local costmap config to be empty and have no sensor input (not sure 100% if it would work). Your best bet is to only use a global path planner, and instead of a local planner that uses sampling, simply use one of the PID controllers that follows the global plan using [PID control](http://wiki.ros.org/tracking_pid) and no sampling. You probably would still need to monitor sensor data for dynamic obstacles that come up in the path, and stop the robot while that dynamic obstacle is detected, and resume motor commands when it leaves.

TLDR:

- Take out local path planner
- launch tracking_pid to follow global plan
- have other code that checks for dynamic obstacles in path
- use cmd_multiplex to use tracking_pid commands unless that^ code says otherwise

Comment: Hmm, thank you for your response. Perchance, do you know if there is anything like that already made? Or if someone teaches how to do that? Thanks in advance.

Comment: It's all just plugging into or removing from move_base. Google tracking_pid. It'll be easy to code something that just stops the robot if an obstacle is detected.

Comment: Got it. I will take a deeper look into it, thanks again, Chad!