# How can I disable the local planner?

Tags: navigation, ros-noetic

I want to make my robot stop avoiding dynamic obstacles, want it to stop in front of them and wait until the path is clear. I came across this post: [how-to-disable-obstacle-avoidance-on-dwa-planner](https://robotics.stackexchange.com/questions/104603/how-to-disable-obstacle-avoidance-on-dwa-planner/104623?noredirect=1). The answer to this post says that I need to take out the local path planner from move_base so that I could apply a tracking_pid algorithm. How can I take out the local planner? I tried to comment it on my move_base launch but it brings up the default planner. Tried to remove my local_costmap and local_planner params but it still works. How could I disable this planner so that only the tracking_pid would move my robot?

Thanks in advance.